# How do I load several feeds sequentially and in order?

Tags: feeds, cron

I have a site which loads its content nodes using [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds). I load several nested taxonomies, and, as indicated in the docs, I use several different feeds. These are called sequentially by hand. How could I configure a cron so the feeds are called in exactly the same order as I would define? I have read the documentation and cannot find it how. Must I configure something here?

[image]

Comment: Please don't create so generic tags; they don't add anything.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure out anything apart from feeds and cron. You are right about 7, but for the others I cannot imagine better ones; I will give it a look. Thanks.